# Showing cookie was not set

Tags: javascript, cookies, three.js, webgl

Trying to make something using bloom and shaders in postpreocessing. But I am getting this error in console with a clear white screen. Even I have cleared my cookies, caches and all.
I have also tried to run this in incognito mode, still not working.(Should be it?)

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
>       http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A
>       future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site
>       requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can
>       review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies
>       and see more details at
>       https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>       https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error is not the source of your problem. Note that it says, "A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies" as in - this is just an informational warning. No functionality has been affected. Can you try recreating this on localhost in incognito mode? That may help you remove the other factors creating spurious warnings.